# AWS Secrets Manager credentials not applied to the Postgres database?

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-secrets-manager

When I create an RDS secret in the AWS console, it does not seem to work in connecting to the database.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The new credentials do not appear to work (e.g. in PgAdmin):

[image]

Additionally there is no entry in any of these tables:

```sql
SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_user

SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_roles

SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_auth_members
```

What else needs to be done?